# MVC passing list from controller to view

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I have a controller that returns a list of view models, like so:

```
public ActionResult Index()
{
   List<DailyPlanListViewModel> viewModels = new List<DailyPlanListViewModel>();
   //do some stuff with the list
   return View(viewModels);
}
```

and a view that takes the list and should display the information

```
@model List<IEnumerable<D2D.Web.ViewModels.DailyPlan.DailyPlanListViewModel>>
```

BUT I get this error, because of the IEnumerable type:

> The model item passed into the dictionary is of type 'System.Collections.Generic.List1[D2D.Web.ViewModels.DailyPlan.DailyPlanListViewModel]', but this dictionary requires a model item of type 'System.Collections.Generic.List1[System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable`1[D2D.Web.ViewModels.DailyPlan.DailyPlanListViewModel]]'.

I can't get it to work. What can I do?

Comment: `@model IEnumerable<D2D.Web.ViewModels.DailyPlan.DailyPlanListViewModel>`

Comment: `@model List<D2D.Web.ViewModels.DailyPlan.DailyPlanListViewModel>`

Comment: try `@model List<D2D.Web.ViewModels.DailyPlan.DailyPlanListViewModel`

Comment: `List<IEnumerable<...>>` should be quite obvious what the error is getting at.

Comment: thx to all, i finally got it working

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to remove the IEnumerable part:

```
@model List<D2D.Web.ViewModels.DailyPlan.DailyPlanListViewModel>
```

Your list is the IEnumerable.

A better way to approach this would be to create another class to wrap this list, so you're only passing one model back to the view instead of a list of models.